# CSS - overflow: hidden property hides sub-menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm using Wordpress, and the page builder (Elementor) generated the following code for a (mega) menu:

```
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-32242">
    <a href="#" class="wpr-menu-item wpr-pointer-item">
        <span>Partners</span>
        <i class="wpr-sub-icon fas" aria-hidden="true"/>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu wpr-sub-menu wpr-animate-sub">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-32243">
            <a href="https://www.example.com/partners/" class="wpr-sub-menu-item">
                <span>Partner list</span>
                <i class="wpr-sub-icon fas wpr-sub-icon-rotate" aria-hidden="true"/>
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu wpr-sub-menu wpr-animate-sub">
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-32244">
                    <a href="https://www.example.com/partners/partner1/" class="wpr-sub-menu-item">
                        <span>Partner1</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-32245">
                    <a href="https://www.example.com/partners/partner2/" class="wpr-sub-menu-item">
                        <span>Partner2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-32246">
                    <a href="https://www.example.com/partners/partner3/" class="wpr-sub-menu-item">
                        <span>Partner3</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-32251">
            <a href="https://www.example.com/become-a-partner/" class="wpr-sub-menu-item">
                <span>Become a partner</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I would like to add a boder-radius to the submenu, but when I try the following the sub-menu (the section with "Partner1", "Partner2", etc) is not visible:

```
ul.sub-menu.wpr-sub-menu {
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I have to add `overflow: hidden;` otherwise the corners disappear.

Any way I can make add the border-radius while having the sub-menu visible?

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes all the codes needed to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If all fails you could apply border-top-left-radius and border-top-right-radius to .wpr-sub-menu:first-child and bottom radiusses to .wpr-sub-menu:last-child. But first you should examine what other rules prevent the submenu from adjusting its dimensions to its content (probably some height or positioning).